# Bash duplicate lines of delimited file reverse order

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Let's assume I have the following text delimited file (delimiter = space). Each line has two integers separated by a space.

Sample input file

```
1 2
1 3
2 1
```

I want to duplicate each line but reversed (the first number within the same line becomes second and the second becomes first). Duplicate lines will be added at the end of file (although the order is not important, since I will sort them later anyway).

Output file

```
1 2
1 3
1 2
2 1
3 1
2 3
```

Is there any awk, sed one-liner to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it using awk (ordering is preserved):

```
awk '{a[NR]=$2 FS $1;print}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;++i)print a[i]}' file.txt
```

It populates an array `a` using the record number `NR` as the key and the reversed line as the value. At the end, it loops through the array printing out all of the values.

To avoid storing all of the lines in memory, you could pass through the file twice instead:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{print;next}{print $2,$1}' file.txt file.txt
```

The first time round, the fields are printed normally. The second time round, `NR` is no longer equal to `FNR`, so the fields are printed in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk '{print $2 " " $1}' test.txt > test1.txt && cat test1.txt >> test.txt && rm test1.txt
```

Simply prints the second field, followed by a space, followed by the first field then appends to the end of the file in two steps. (It would be dangerous with very large files to simply append to the end of the file immediately.)

Comment: Thanks. Already upvoted. But Tom's solution is more elegant, so I will accept his. Thanks

Comment: No need for `printf` - `{print $2, $1}` would be sufficient.

Comment: This is dangerous. If `test.txt` is big enough to begin with, you may fill up your disk, as `awk` will read past the original end-of-file and process the stuff you just appended. And then the stuff after that... And then some more... For smaller files, though, it may be ok, as the entire file will be read in and fed to `awk` before any of the output gets appended.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I have incorporated your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is huge as some people have suggested then this would be faster than running awk twice:

```
cp file1 file2 && awk '{print $2,$1}' file1 >> file2
```

or:

```
(cat file1 && awk '{print $2,$1}' file1) > file2
```

but otherwise just use Toms awk command or this if you don't want to specify the file name twice:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ARGV[ARGC]=ARGV[ARGC-1];ARGC++} NR==FNR{print;next} {print $2,$1}' file1 > file2
```

Comment: I get weird output. Does not it a \n somewhere?

Comment: I don't know what `Does not it a \n somewhere` means. If you're getting weird output then it's because you have weird input. Try `cat -v` on your input file to see if it contains control chars, the most likely of which is control-Ms if your file was created on Windows - if so remove them with `dos2unix` or similar.

Comment: Sorry the file was created on Windows, so I had to run dos2unix filename and after that awk worked correctly.